# both FULL OUTER JOIN and WHERE to get true result?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wrote this script. if we comment the two part in WHERE clause, some rows ignored in result. can somebody tell me why?

In the first query it works true as FULL OUTER JOIN, but in the second query, the query results as INNER JOIN and return only one row, despite of using the WHERE clause in which the UNKNOWN condition resolves.

```
DECLARE @ALLDATA TABLE 
( 
[Id]        INT,
[T3Id]      INT,
[StockId]   INT,
[Serial]    INT,
[ISDel]     INT
)
INSERT INTO @ALLDATA ([Id],[T3Id],[StockId],[Serial],[ISDel])
Select 5 AS [Id],11 AS [T3Id],5 AS [StockId],0 AS [Serial],1 AS [ISDel]
UNION ALL
Select 1 AS [Id],11 AS [T3Id],5 AS [StockId],0 AS [Serial],1 AS [ISDel]
UNION ALL
Select 1 AS [Id],11 AS [T3Id],5 AS [StockId],1 AS [Serial],-1 AS [ISDel]
UNION ALL
Select 2 AS [Id],11 AS [T3Id],5 AS [StockId],2 AS [Serial],-1 AS [ISDel]
UNION ALL
Select 3 AS [Id],11 AS [T3Id],5 AS [StockId],3 AS [Serial],-1 AS [ISDel]
UNION ALL
Select 4 AS [Id],11 AS [T3Id],5 AS [StockId],4 AS [Serial],-1 AS [ISDel]

SELECT 'WITH CONDITIONS:'

SELECT 
 ISNULL(DataIns.[Id],DataDEL.[Id])      AS [Id]
,ISNULL(DataDEL.[StockId],-1)           AS [OLDStockId]
,ISNULL(DataDEL.[Serial],0)             AS [OLDSerial]
,ISNULL(DataIns.[StockId],-1)           AS [NEWStockId]
,ISNULL(DataIns.[Serial],0)             AS [NEWSerial]
,ISNULL(DataIns.[T3Id],DataDEL.[T3Id])  AS [T3Id]
,DataIns.[ISDel]                        AS [ISDel1]
,DataDEL.[ISDel]                        AS [ISDel2]
FROM @ALLDATA       AS DataIns
FULL OUTER JOIN @ALLDATA AS DataDEL 
ON 
DataDEL.Id = DataIns.Id 
AND  
DataDEL.ISDel = 1 
AND 
DataIns.ISDel = -1
WHERE ISNULL(DataDEL.[ISDel],1) = 1 AND ISNULL(DataIns.[ISDel],-1) = -1 

SELECT 'WITHOUT CONDITIONS:'

SELECT 
 ISNULL(DataIns.[Id],DataDEL.[Id])      AS [Id]
,ISNULL(DataDEL.[StockId],-1)           AS [OLDStockId]
,ISNULL(DataDEL.[Serial],0)             AS [OLDSerial]
,ISNULL(DataIns.[StockId],-1)           AS [NEWStockId]
,ISNULL(DataIns.[Serial],0)             AS [NEWSerial]
,ISNULL(DataIns.[T3Id],DataDEL.[T3Id])  AS [T3Id]
,DataIns.[ISDel]                        AS [ISDel1]
,DataDEL.[ISDel]                        AS [ISDel2]
FROM @ALLDATA       AS DataIns
FULL OUTER JOIN @ALLDATA AS DataDEL 
ON 
DataDEL.Id = DataIns.Id 
--AND 
--  DataDEL.ISDel = 1 
--AND 
--  DataIns.ISDel = -1
WHERE ISNULL(DataDEL.[ISDel],1) = 1 AND ISNULL(DataIns.[ISDel],-1) = -1
```

Desired Output:

```
1    5  0    5  1   11    -1       1
2   -1  0    5  2   11    -1    NULL
3   -1  0    5  3   11    -1    NULL
4   -1  0    5  4   11    -1    NULL
5    5  0   -1  0   11  NULL       1
```

Comment: Please show actual sample outputs. Don't make us run your code.

Answer (score 3):

> Can somebody tell me why?

Because it's the way `FULL OUTER JOIN` works.

When you comment out the additional conditions in the `ON` clause, you in fact are getting an `INNER JOIN` (since `id` will always produce at least one match in a self-join).

Your first query does not make sense to me as well (or you have some really complicated requirements).

I believe you wanted this:

```
SELECT   ISNULL(DataIns.[Id],DataDEL.[Id])      AS [Id]
        ,ISNULL(DataDEL.[StockId],-1)           AS [OLDStockId]
        ,ISNULL(DataDEL.[Serial],0)             AS [OLDSerial]
        ,ISNULL(DataIns.[StockId],-1)           AS [NEWStockId]
        ,ISNULL(DataIns.[Serial],0)             AS [NEWSerial]
        ,ISNULL(DataIns.[T3Id],DataDEL.[T3Id])  AS [T3Id]
        ,DataIns.[ISDel]                        AS [ISDel1]
        ,DataDEL.[ISDel]                        AS [ISDel2]
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    @alldata
        WHERE   isdel = 1
        ) dataDel
FULL JOIN
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    @alldata
        WHERE   isdel = -1
        ) dataIns
ON      dataDel.id = dataIns.id
```

Comment: thanks Quassnoi, but it is not. I want SQL to do FULL OUTER JOIN, but I have to also add some extra expression in WHERE and I don't know why.

Comment: @aporia: could you please post the resultset you want to get?

Comment: I add my expected output at the end of the post. that is the result of the first query. I think the last query must also return that logically.

Comment: @aporia: my query returns exactly what you want (and is more efficient than your first one). Your last query is a self-joinon `id`. Since it's a self-join, there will be always a match: whichever `id` you take on the left side, there will be always at least one same `id` on the right side (from the same record), and vice versa, so it's an `INNER JOIN` in fact. This also means that `isDel` can never be a `NULL` and never be equal to `1` and `-1` at the same time, so the matches on same records will always be filtered out. Just comment out the `WHERE` condition in your last query and see.